# Issue when trying to UPDATE table on LINKED SERVER

Tags: sql-server, odbc, firebird, linked-server, firebird2.5

I connected my MS SQL Server database to Firebird using odbc. When I use a `SELECT` statement it works perfectly. The error occurs when I try to `UPDATE`. I get this error message:

> The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "server_name" could not update table

The strange thing is, it can update some other tables in the same db, but not a select few.

Comment: Does the Firebird user used to connect have update privileges on the table in question? Also, please provide a [mre].

Comment: maybe you have tables with the same name in some another server/database ?

Comment: @Arioch'The hmmm.. there shouldnt be.
MarkRotteveel IT HAS! 
Some weird things are happening, because when I deleted the table and created it again, it worked! and when we ran the whole process again, it got an error again, and I cant update the table.